# JSON issue with getting variable

Tags: javascript, json

Hello everyone I have an issue here with JSON file creation. The issue is that I have variable that updates and stores public-key of the account created through the plugin and this variable does not parse or otherwise go to the JSON creation function i am using regardless of what I try, I have also added " around the key but it is still not working.

```
            var date = new Date();
        var TS = date.getTime();
        //PKey = toString();
        var xyz = {
                "transaction":
                        {
                            "timeStamp": TS, ///needs to be changed to current timestamp from creating of account
                            "fee": 20, ///have to check
                            "type": 4097,
                            "deadline": TS + 30000, ///need to be changed
                            "version": -1744830462, /// main(real) network 1744830465,
                            "signer": PubKey,
                            "modifications": [
                                {
                                    "modificationType": 1,
                                    "cosignatoryAccount": "22dfd68cc4d6148500d722c0e603c29671b5ad98c5c3f7f20528a16a26082f60"
                                }
                            ],
                            "minCosignatories" : {
                                "relativeChange": 2
                            }
                        },
                "privateKey": PKey
                };
        xyz["transaction"]["signer"] = PubKey;
```

It works perfectly with the Timestamp variable but then again it is an integer variable not string. Please help out.

This is the error that I get from the web console,

> {"timeStamp":124860889,"error":"Internal Server
>   Error","message":"expected value for property signer, but none was
>   found","status":500}

Comment: From the error it's loook like either your `PubKey` is null or empty. Please check.

Comment: I have checked and it is not null or empty it is perfectly stored into the system

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. even though the variable was not empty it was not persistent through the hole of the JS structure. I could not find way to make it persistent by itself so I just had to include the code into the function. If anyone has other solutions please do tell I will vote for them.